# How to get all the values from a JSON array

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get all the keys from a JSON array.
The link of the JSON is: [this one](https://api-cloud.bitmart.com/account/v1/currencies)

And the code I'm using is:

```
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Text.Json.Nodes
Public Class Form1
    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using http = New HttpClient
            Dim url = "https://api-cloud.bitmart.com/account/v1/currencies"
            Dim json = JsonNode.Parse(Await http.GetStreamAsync(url))
            Dim naming As [String] = json("currency") 

            RichTextBox1.Text = json("currency")
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

But clicking the Button doesn't populate anything. The RichTextBox stays empty,
while I want to get all the values `( es : "DFC, "$GM", "BBK" ecc)`

I'm using `.net6` but a framework.net solution would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: So, during debugging when you inspect json variable, does it have any content?  Very off the top of my head, but fell like you're missing a step here.  Think you need to do something like Dim response = await Http.GetStreamAsync, then work with the response.content

Comment: hey @Hursey, where I am supposed to try that code? between what? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the supplied answer, I think should get you moving in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## .Net Core answer

Take a look at my suggestion below. I can see that you are missing several steps in parsing the Json data as well as not getting the `result` of the `GetStreamAsync` operation.

```
Dim streamData As Stream = Nothing
Using http As HttpClient = New HttpClient
    Dim url As String = "https://api-cloud.bitmart.com/account/v1/currencies"

    Dim t As Task(Of Stream) = http.GetStreamAsync(url)
    streamData = t.Result
End Using

Dim jsonResponse As JsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(streamData)
Dim jsonData As JsonNode = jsonResponse("data")
Dim jsonCurrencies As JsonNode = jsonData("currencies")

Dim c As String = String.Empty
Dim n As String = String.Empty
For Each jsonCurrency As JsonNode In jsonCurrencies.AsArray()
    c += jsonCurrency("currency").ToString + " "
    n += jsonCurrency("network").ToString + " "
Next


Debug.WriteLine(c)
Debug.WriteLine(n)
```

This will output all of the currencies downloaded from: https://api-cloud.bitmart.com/account/v1/currencies

My test program doesn't work well with Async/Await operations so I removed the call to Await. I believe you can put it back in without issue.

This is a .Net Core answer, I believe for .Net Framework you will need to use a different Json parser, such as Newtonsoft.

## .Net Framework 4.8 answer

This version makes use of `Newtonsoft Json parser` and is slightly different to the .Net Core version as it make use of Async/Await

```
Private Async Sub DownloadData()
    Dim jsonString As String
    Using http As HttpClient = New HttpClient
        Dim url As String = "https://api-cloud.bitmart.com/account/v1/currencies"

        Dim streamData As Stream = Await http.GetStreamAsync(url)

        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(streamData)
            jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd
        End Using
        streamData.Close()
    End Using

    Dim jsonResponse As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
    Dim jsonData As JObject = CType(jsonResponse("data"), JObject)
    Dim jsonCurrencies As JArray = CType(jsonData("currencies"), JArray)

    Dim c As String = String.Empty
    Dim n As String = String.Empty
    For Each jsonCurrency As JObject In jsonCurrencies
        c += jsonCurrency("currency").ToString + " "
        n += jsonCurrency("network").ToString + " "
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine(c)
    Debug.WriteLine(n)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @JayV thanks for your reply.
i've just try your code but the output is just "DFA", it doesn't return anything else.

Comment: @878757 `DFA` is the last currency in the list. This tells me everything except the last line in your code is fine. Try something like `RichTextBox1.Text += json("currency")` to concatenate the currency list instead of replacing it each time

Comment: I've tried my code again now as you are stating and modify the last line. But i got the error: + operator is not define for string type and jsonNode

Comment: RichTextBox1.Text += jsonCurrency("currency").ToString + " "

Comment: So you are using your code now :). It is working !
Just a thing. If i want to get also the value "network", how can I do ? i've tried with:
 `Dim jsonchain As JsonNode = jsonData("network")` and
`For Each jsonCurrency As JsonNode In jsonCurrencies.AsArray() And jsonchain As Jsonnode In jsonchain.asarray()`
      but obviously the loop is incorrect.
Would it be possible? thanks a lot

Comment: @878757 I've editted my answer to include the `network` value as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for your 2 examples! Taking in consideration the first one, I get the error "Cannot transcode invalid UTF-8 JSON text to UTF-16 string." on the line `n += jsonCurrency("network").ToString + " "` which I don't understand where to format it correctly.  Also, since c and n are values that are supposed to be together, would it be possible to make something like " richtextbox1.text= c+n in each line.. Thanks!

Comment: Note that System.Text.Json is available for .Net Framework. Just get the [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) -- That JSON would be **much easier** to handle if you deserialize to .Net classes instead of using JsonNode.

Comment: Jimi tbh I've tried you code from a while ago, but that was meant to for for a single json key. In this case I need to make a loop, so this [link](https://pastebin.com/CfdZuAmS) is what I've tried so far. What I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: @878757 You don't need Task.WhenAll() for that, it's just `dim json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api-cloud.bitmart.com/account/v1/currencies")`. Then, as mentioned, deserialize to concrete .Net classes instead of using JsonElements. The JSON structure is quite simple here. You can use [JsonUtils](https://jsonutils.com/) to generate your classes, it can produce .Net classes in the VB.Net language. -- You can then loop the `currencies` list of class objects as usual.

Comment: @JayV do you think that this approach would work also in this case? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034831/how-to-iterate-through-all-keys-of-json-node)