# How to iterate through all keys of json node

Tags: json, vb.net, .net-core, console-application

I'm trying to scrap the key values from this website [API](https://api.hotbit.io/api/v1/market.status24h) and it seems the json format it's not an array.
I'm working with console .Net core 6.0 using System.Text.Json.Nodes

The code I'm using is :

```
    Dim streamData As Stream = Nothing
    Using http As HttpClient = New HttpClient
        Dim url As String = "https://api.hotbit.io/api/v1/market.status24h"

        Dim t As Task(Of Stream) = http.GetStreamAsync(url)
        streamData = t.Result
    End Using

    Dim jsonResponse As JsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(streamData)
    Dim jsonData As JsonNode = jsonResponse("result")

    Dim c As String = String.Empty

    For Each jsonCurrency As JsonNode In jsonData.AsObject
        c += jsonCurrency("last").ToString + " "
    Next
```

but I get the error:

> Cannot convert type 'KeyValuePair(Of String, JsonNode)' in JsonNode

What Am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using

```
 Dim result As JsonObject = jsonResponse("result").AsObject
    
 For Each kvp In result.AsEnumerable
     c &= kvp.Value("last").ToString & ", "
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to represent your JSON, like this:

```vb
Public Class MarketStatus
    Public Property IsChange As Boolean
    Public Property period As Integer
    Public Property open As String
    Public Property last As String
    Public Property high As String
    Public Property low As String
    Public Property volume As String
    Public Property deal As String
    Public Property close As String
    Public Property base_volume As String
    Public Property quote_volume As String
End Class

Public Class Payload
    Public Property _error As Object
    Public Property result As Result
    Public Property id As Integer
End Class

Public Class Result

    <JsonPropertyName("0xBTCBTC")>
    Public Property _0xBTCBTC As MarketStatus

    <JsonPropertyName("0xBTCETH")>
    Public Property _0xBTCETH As MarketStatus

    <JsonPropertyName("0xCASHUSDT")>
    Public Property _0xCASHUSDT As MarketStatus

    <JsonPropertyName("1INCH1D3LUSDT")>
    Public Property _1INCH1D3LUSDT As MarketStatus

    ' etc...
End Class
```

Now you can deserialize the entire payload by using JsonSerializer.Deserialize or JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync:

```vb
Dim payloadObject = Await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(Of Payload)(streamData)
```

**Update**

Per our conversation in the comments of this answer, you want to get the last value of each MarketStatus without having to type each one manually. What you can do is:

1. Use reflection to get every property of the Result class
2. Loop over the collection
3. Use PropertyInfo.GetValue to get the value of the deserialized object

Here is an example using the same variable names as above:

```vb
For Each propertyInformation In GetType(Result).GetProperties()
    Dim status = DirectCast(propertyInformation.GetValue(payloadObject.result), MarketStatus)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}.last = {1}", propertyInformation.Name, status.last)
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/USaAgc

Comment: Ho David thanks for your reply. I cannot do what you are suggesting because the result would be huuge, they are around 1000 results, that s why I m trying to make a loop to get all the "last" values

Comment: The payload size doesn't make any difference in terms of performance since you would need to loop over the values anyways. If you don't want to write out the property names, that's something different because you can create a simple script to automatically generate the property names for you.

Comment: I was thinking to a solution similar to this on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993201/how-to-get-all-the-values-from-a-json-array) but that works for array. Do you think it might be possible in this case?

Comment: @878757 - I think I see what you're saying. You can use reflection to get the properties of the Result class, loop over the properties, and get their value to get the respective last value. Is this more or less what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey David, you can see that with that answer I can parse all the values that have the  same key. That would be a solution in my case, cause basically I want to parse all the values ( that are crypto coins ) like "0xBTCBTC and their last prices  0.00003427" like this image [link](https://imgur.com/dtgl58B) but all the others properties I'm not interested on. Thanks

Comment: I obviously tried to use that code In my case, but it seems the json Im working on now it doesn't have arrays.

Comment: Like I said, you can use reflection to loop over the properties of results then get the last property of the currently iterated value. If you want an example of this, I can provide you with one.

Comment: @878757 - Please see updated answer.

Comment: You aren't following what I'm saying. 1. Have Visual Studio create the class definitions for you by using Paste Special > Paste as JSON. 2. Deserialize the JSON literal to the root object (I renamed the class to Payload in my example). 3. Use reflection to get the properties of the Result class. 4. Loop over the properties and get the last property of the currently iterated property using the deserialized payload.

Comment: which means I still need to copy paste all that huge amount of json on visual studio?

Comment: @878757 - Aside from the class definitions it is like 5 lines of code. I can't help you anymore at this point.

Comment: I solved. Look at the answer if you want