# 'The node must be of type 'JsonObject'.'

Tags: json, vb.net, .net-4.8

I'm trying to parse [this Json](https://api.hotbit.io/api/v1/market.deals?market=KIBA/USDT&limit=150&last_id=1521100930&api_key=44812d8f-66d3-01c0-94c3b29305040b03&sign=98EEC3D69D3F70F9BDFED901984B2AA4)

With the code:

```
 Dim streamData As Stream = Nothing
        Using http As New HttpClient
            Dim url As String = "https://api.hotbit.io/api/v1/market.deals?market=KIBA/USDT&limit=150&last_id=1521100930&api_key=44812d8f-66d3-01c0-94c3b29305040b03&sign=98EEC3D69D3F70F9BDFED901984B2AA4"

            Dim t As Task(Of Stream) = http.GetStreamAsync(url)
            streamData = t.Result
        End Using

        Dim jsonResponse As JsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(streamData)
        Dim result As JsonObject = jsonResponse("result").AsObject
        Dim c As String = String.Empty
        For Each kvp In result.AsEnumerable
            c &= kvp.Value("price").ToString & vbCr
        Next
        RichTextBox1.Text = c
    End Sub
```

but I keep getting the error at debug

> The node must be of type 'JsonObject'.'
> on the line

```
 Dim result As JsonObject = jsonResponse("result").AsObject
```

How it comes it gives an error If I'm already trying to parse it as a Jsonobject?

Thanks

Comment: What about this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068085/11392290. What kind of game are you playing here?

Comment: [link](https://api.hotbit.io/api/v1/market.deals?market=KIBA/USDT&limit=150&last_id=1521100930&api_key=44812d8f-66d3-01c0-94c3b29305040b03&sign=98EEC3D69D3F70F9BDFED901984B2AA4) this is the json I'm working on now, while that one is [link](https://api.hotbit.io/api/v1/market.status24h) . As you can see, I can't use David code because in this case, there are no property names like `onPropertyName("0xBTCBTC")>
    Public Property _0xBTCBTC As MarketStatus`
thus this [link](https://pastebin.com/kSyi0hc9) is the full code trying David code.

Comment: which doesn't work cause I'm getting the error "'Form1.Trades' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression." on the line        `Dim status = DirectCast(propertyInformation.GetValue(Trades), Result)`
If you have any suggestions, I would be happuy to listen it. Or If I misunderstood something, I would be happy to know from you, which one . But no one is playing games here. So i don't know why you stated that.

Comment: In both your questions I can see the same json.  And the same code will be workig the same way. "result" is an  array, and it can not be parsed as JsonObject even using a stupid Text.Json. Just change JsonObject to JsonNode.This is what error message advices you.

Comment: Do you mean like this?  `Dim result As JsonNode = jsonResponse("result").AsObject`

I'm getting the error : AsEnumerable' is not a member of 'JsonNode'.

Comment: I forgot VB syntax already, last time I used it  was 11 years ago. But it should be something like jsonResponse.Root("result") as JsonNode

Comment: it will give me an error if I use what you just suggest me:   `Dim result As JsonObject = jsonResponse.Root("result").asjsonnode` as .AsJsonNode is not even part of the IntelliSense

Comment: I didnt use dot. You should know vb syntax if you are using it, Maybe just  Dim result As JsonNode = jsonResponse.Root("result");

Comment: Tried, but now it says **'AsEnumerable' is not a member of 'JsonNode'.**

Comment: This is another bad idea to use Text.Json.  And It is a disaster to use it together with vb.net. you can not even translate to vb net the simpliest code. In C# it will be -  JsonNode result = jsonResponse.Root["result"] as JsonNode;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a go at this..

- Paste this into a new class file:

```
Namespace HotBit
    Partial Public Class TradeCollection
        <JsonProperty("error")>
        Public Property [Error] As Object
        <JsonProperty("result")>
        Public Property Result As List(Of Result)
        <JsonProperty("id")>
        Public Property Id As Long
    End Class

    Partial Public Class Result
        <JsonProperty("id")>
        Public Property Id As Long
        <JsonProperty("time")>
        Public Property Time As Long
        <JsonProperty("price")>
        Public Property Price As String
        <JsonProperty("amount")>
        <JsonConverter(GetType(ParseStringConverter))>
        Public Property Amount As Long
        <JsonProperty("type")>
        Public Property Type As TypeEnum
    End Class

    Public Enum TypeEnum
        Buy
        Sell
    End Enum

    Partial Public Class TradeCollection
        Public Shared Function FromJson(ByVal json As String) As TradeCollection
            Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TradeCollection)(json, Settings)
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Module Serialize
        <Extension()>
        Public Function ToJson(ByVal self As TradeCollection) As String
            Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Settings)
        End Function
    End Module

    Friend Module Converter
        Public ReadOnly Settings As JsonSerializerSettings = New JsonSerializerSettings With {
            .MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            .DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
        }
    End Module

    Friend Class ParseStringConverter
        Inherits JsonConverter

        Public Overrides Function CanConvert(ByVal t As Type) As Boolean
            Return t Is GetType(Long) OrElse t Is GetType(Long?)
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function ReadJson(ByVal reader As JsonReader, ByVal t As Type, ByVal existingValue As Object, ByVal serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
            If reader.TokenType = JsonToken.Null Then Return Nothing
            Dim value = serializer.Deserialize(Of String)(reader)
            Dim l As Long

            If Long.TryParse(value, l) Then
                Return l
            End If

            Throw New Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long")
        End Function

        Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(ByVal writer As JsonWriter, ByVal untypedValue As Object, ByVal serializer As JsonSerializer)
            If untypedValue Is Nothing Then
                serializer.Serialize(writer, Nothing)
                Return
            End If

            Dim value = CLng(untypedValue)
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString())
            Return
        End Sub

        Public Shared ReadOnly Singleton As ParseStringConverter = New ParseStringConverter()
    End Class

    Friend Class TypeEnumConverter
        Inherits JsonConverter

        Public Overrides Function CanConvert(ByVal t As Type) As Boolean
            Return t Is GetType(TypeEnum) OrElse t Is GetType(TypeEnum?)
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function ReadJson(ByVal reader As JsonReader, ByVal t As Type, ByVal existingValue As Object, ByVal serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
            If reader.TokenType = JsonToken.Null Then Return Nothing
            Dim value = serializer.Deserialize(Of String)(reader)

            Select Case value
                Case "buy"
                    Return TypeEnum.Buy
                Case "sell"
                    Return TypeEnum.Sell
            End Select

            Throw New Exception("Cannot unmarshal type TypeEnum")
        End Function

        Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(ByVal writer As JsonWriter, ByVal untypedValue As Object, ByVal serializer As JsonSerializer)
            If untypedValue Is Nothing Then
                serializer.Serialize(writer, Nothing)
                Return
            End If

            Dim value = CType(untypedValue, TypeEnum)

            Select Case value
                Case TypeEnum.Buy
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, "buy")
                    Return
                Case TypeEnum.Sell
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, "sell")
                    Return
            End Select

            Throw New Exception("Cannot marshal type TypeEnum")
        End Sub

        Public Shared ReadOnly Singleton As TypeEnumConverter = New TypeEnumConverter()
    End Class
End Namespace
```

- Then install Newtonsoft (if not already) and `Imports` it
- Then `Imports HotBit` (or if you changed the Namespace of the "paste this" above, Imports that new namespace
- Then do your request and query the result e.g.:

```
Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim s = New WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.hotbit.io/api/v1/market.deals?market=KIBA/USDT&limit=150&last_id=1521100930&api_key=44812d8f-66d3-01c0-94c3b29305040b03&sign=98EEC3D69D3F70F9BDFED901984B2AA4")

        Dim tc = TradeCollection.FromJson(s)

        Dim prices = String.Join(","c, tc.Result.Select(Function(r) r.Price))

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Caius, I've just implemented your code and I 'm getting the Prices all together, So I'm trying to build the string like: `RichTextBox1.Text = prices & " - " & tipo & " - " & " - " & time & " - " & amount & vbCr`
with the code `Dim prices = String.Join(","c, tc.Result.Select(Function(r) r.Price))
        Dim tipo = String.Join(","c, tc.Result.Select(Function(r) r.Type))
        Dim time = String.Join(","c, tc.Result.Select(Function(r) r.Time))
        Dim amount = String.Join(","c, tc.Result.Select(Function(r) r.Amount))`

Comment: but it keeps giving me as output: all prices, than all type, then all time and then all the amounts. Where can I build the lines? Thanks

Comment: *I 'm getting the Prices all together* - it was all I could determine you original code as trying to do (though used a comma, not a vbCr)

Comment: Take a look at this perhaps:  `Dim all = String.Join(vbCrLf, tc.Result.Select(Function(r) $"{r.Price} - {r.Type} - {r.Time} - {r.Amount}"))`

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you do it - this is just LINQ but if you don't like LINQ, do `ForEach r as Result In tc.Result .... textBox.AppendText( r.Price .ToString())` etc

Comment: Pause the code in the debugger and inspect the `tc` object, and the Result array (which ois an array of Result objects)

Comment: `Dim all = String.Join(vbCrLf, tc.Result.Select(Function(r) $"{r.Price} - {r.Type} - {r.Time} - {r.Amount}"))` works perfectly, i didn't know it was LINQ. Sorry I'm quite a beginner :)..
I've tried also the loop for each, with `Dim tc = TradeCollection.FromJson(s)
        For Each r As Result In tc.Result
            RichTextBox1.Text &= (r.Price.ToString() & " - " & (r.Type.ToString())) & vbCr
        Next`
And they both work perfectly! For a easier manipulation of string I will prefer the Non Linq solution, btw taking in consideration LINQ too as my next step. Thanks a lot Caius!

Comment: Caius, if you don't mind I would take advantage of the situation to ask you something. Why developers would use this long and difficult ( at least to me ) ways to solve this cases while basically someone can just write 20 lines like the code I've posted in my question? I mean, probably that wouldn't be the perfect code, but is basically allowing you not to create classes and json properties, save time and eventhough I don't really know if there is a solution to my code, would be nice to know the reasons why someone would choose either this or that way. Still thanks.

Comment: Oh; it's not long and difficult - it's really easy. I went to http://quicktype.io and pasted the JSON in there. It generated a huge block of code as C# (QT doesn't support VB, but it doesnt really matter, C# and VB are the same thing) - then I went to ICsharpCode's converter and converted the C# to VB. I had to fix it up in two places because the converter converted `is` to `Is` when VB needs `=` and that gave me the massive block of code in the top of the question. If I;m working in C# (usually) i can skip the conversion part.

Comment: There are websites that take JSON and churn out VB directly; I just have a preference for QuickType because the code it makes is very nice and quite advanced.. So.. All consuming some API that spits out JSON is a "copy URL, paste URL, copy JSON, paste JSON, copy code, paste code, copy the `TradeCollection.FromJson(s)` from the top down to where it's needed" - so 6 copy/paste operations really..

Comment: Now, even that is actually more complex than it needs to be. APIs these days open publish something called a swagger/openAPI spec which is a json document that describes the service in full, the names of all its endpoints, parameters, what it takes in and what it spits out.,. and there are other tools like AutoRest or NSwag that consume that file and write every bit of code you need, even the HttpClient bit that does the send and receive, the deserialize, so you end up just writing something like `Dim result = new ApiClient().GetMarketDeals("KIBA","USDT")` and result is like `tc`

Comment: The "20 or so lines of code" in the question are fairly hard work though; parsing a document and then crawling round its structure as a set of json objects and elements, picking out bits by typing names into strings is a bit like reading a CSV file in as a string, and cutting it up with split and indexes, and seeing if it string Contains something else.. It will work, but generally in an OO language we like to find ways to convert a string representation of an object into an actual class then we can use the rest of VS features (like intellisense) to write code that reshapes it

Comment: hey Caius, that's amazing! I never hear about a tool like quicktype.io ! I've just used for a little json and tried, I've managed to basically do everything but an erorr persist and I registered a gif to show you. This tool might save lots of questions here on StackOverFlow ahah. Probably I diidn't setted properly on quicktype, look [link](https://imgur.com/0dMJEFg) . Now I'm realizing that what I thought was difficult, is achievable!

Comment: Looks like QT isnt interpreting that particular json as having an array of results - you can see that the property is just defined as `Result as Result` rather than eg `Result as List(Of Result)` so Result cannot be ForEach'd - what is the link to the json that you paste? Either the json doesn't represent an array or it's more like a dictionary - would need to see it

Comment: The Json is as simple as this [link](https://api.hotbit.io/api/v1/balance.query?assets=[%22KIBA%22,%22USDT%22]&api_key=44812d8f-66d3-01c0-94c3b29305040b03&sign=9B71D3778008A9CAF712F19997B137E8) 
I've tried also getting the list as output instead of the array  List<T> instead of the array T[] which you are suggesting it might be not present in the json. 
In Particular, I'm expecting an output like: ** KIBA 
 - available : 61736400 - freeze: 0**  and ** USDT - available - 0.01085321498064 - freeze : 0 **

Comment: I also think I might need to consider to study json formats cause I don't really know yet when a json got arrays or a dictionary. Thanks Caius

Comment: The Result property in that json isn't an array, it's more like a Dictionary. Here is JSON that is an array of Person: `[{name:John,age:20},{name:Bill,age:37}]`. Here is JSON that is a dictionary: `{dict:{John:{age:20},Bill:{age:37}}}` - dictionaries are `{ }` and have varying keys that map to data, arrays are `{ }` objects inside  `[ ]`. Dictionaries are a bit more of a pain in the ass to work with, usually because some of the info you want is in the Key, which means it's variable, and has to be accessed via string rather than property name

Comment: I appreciated your explaination. So in this case, on quicktipe what are the differences I need to set in order to get an output like the one I'm expecting? ( like using list instead of arrays?! )
I setted Result as List(Of Result) in the class, and now I'm trying to work out on the request. Since you stated before I can't foreach's this case, How do you think Am i supposed to proceed? I've tried with 
`Dim ts = TradeCollection.FromJson((Await s))
RichTextBox1.Text &= (ts.Kiba.ToString() & " - " & (ts.amount.ToString()))`
but i get " kiba and usdt are not members of TradeCollection

Comment: My doubts basically starts with the dictionaries, because if with an array I got the key "Person" which i don't need to "parse" but I can easily parse the "details" of it, in the dictionary, instead,  I need to parse also the keys + details, so not just age:30 sex=male, but also the name John, Bill, etc. Hope it just need a little change of the code,without changin from 0 the code you already gave me. In that case it would send me to confusion. Thanks Caius

Comment: The code I gave isn't suitable for parsing this shape of json; you need a new code for every different shape. See if hotbit publish an openapi/swagger spec

Comment: *I setted Result as List(Of Result) in the class* - you can't necessarily do this; the code shape must match the json shape and you don't control the json shape; you can't just change the code to be a collection of the json doesn't have it, you have to parse the json as you find it unless you're writing custom routines to do it